# simple kendo grid implementation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement Kendo Grid with HtmlHelper extension

my controller class is 'Store', view is 'viewStores' and data I am trying to bind using method 'StoreRead'. I am using visual studio 2012, .net 4.5 with mvc 4 and razor...

here is my code..

```
   public ActionResult viewStores()
{
   //return View(GetStores());
    return View();
}

public ActionResult StoreRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
    return Json(GetStores().ToDataSourceResult(request));
 }

private static IEnumerable<Store> GetStores()
{
    var db_store = new AppContext();

    return db_store.Stores.Select(store => new Store
    {
        storeID = store.storeID,
        address = store.address,
        postcode = store.postcode,
        city = store.city,
        Country = store.Country
    });

}
```

view

```
@model KendoAspNetBundles.Models.Store

<h2>viewStores</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoAspNetBundles.Models.Store>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(s => s.storeID);
columns.Bound(s => s.address);
columns.Bound(s => s.postcode);
columns.Bound(s => s.city);
columns.Bound(s => s.Country);
})
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .Ajax() 
   .Read(read => read.Action("StoreRead", "Store")) 
 )
.Pageable()
 )
```

model

```
 public class Store
 {
   public int storeID { get; set; }
   public string address { get; set; }
   public string postcode { get; set; }
   public string city { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: i am not getting data in my kendo grid table in view, i believe i am not binding data correctly... i just want simple implementation of kendo grid... many thanks

Comment: i have managed to crack it.... my mistake i was not binding data properly